# How to extract string within a string in a vector string

Tags: c++

Imagine a code like this:

```
vector<string> lsLineNumbers;
    lsLineNumbers.push_back("9, 0xbaadf00d, 3, 4");
    lsLineNumbers.push_back("0xcoffee99, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 0xdeadbeef, 78");
```

When you look in the debugger it looks like string array lsLineNumbers[0] = "9, 0xbaadf00d, 3, 4" and lsLineNumbers[1] = "0xcoffee99, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 0xdeadbeef, 78"

How to extract these number strings out so that I can do string to integer conversion? I can do it manually but I am sure there is a function for this. I would imagine a something like this ...

```
for (i = 0; i < lsLineNumbers.size(); i++) [
    while((str = getstring(lsLineNumbers[0])) != '\0') {
        num = _atoi64(str);
        cout << num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the above link regarding how to split a string on commas, in your case.

Comment: Wow!! Yes that should do it!! Thanks Cyber. I will check it out and then then mark this as the answer.

Comment: You cannot mark comments as answers. Because they are not answers.

Comment: Yes thanks Cyber the first split example did the trick. This case can be closed as done.